# How can I consume A web-service reference like a dll

Tags: c#, web-services, dll, reference

I have a small question: Can we consume a web-service reference like a sample dll? 
I mean something like following: 1. Add reference to assembly in the references 2. add namespace to using (using mywebservice) 3. use it in code like:

```
var service = new  mywebservice.Service1();
var result = service.GetSomething()?
```

Why I'm asking? It's because of I tried but I get a "strange" error: Cannot load assembly "MyService.dll version, and so on". Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain how exactly codecompileunit fits into the problem?  Also post any related code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

What you should note is what the name space is that you put your proxy under. It's the namespace that decide the what you should type instead of "mywebservice"

Comment: My scenario is a little bit different. I discover the webservice, compile the CodeCompileUnit, save the resulting assembly. Then, I want to reuse it in some projects, but like a sample reference.

Comment: Ok, but just compile the project and go to your bin folder and use the DLL.

Comment: I tried. But I was unable to load it. I get an error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Service1.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perfectly create a WCF Service Reference (aka a client proxy) and stick that in an assembly purely meant to serve as a centralized, shareable client proxy. This way, when adding a service operation, you don't have to update the reference in all projects that consume your service, but just update the reference in the assembly.

Please note that if the service reference was configured to reuses types found in assemblies referenced by the client proxy project, you also need to add references to those assemblies to the project using your client proxy assembly.

> Cannot load assembly "MyService.dll version, and so on"

That is a symptom, usually explained by errors surrounding that error. It could prove really useful if you showed all relevant warnings and errors in your question.

You probably just need to add a reference to `System.ServiceModel` to the project using your client proxy assembly, are missing other assembly references or your service project fails to build so it acutally can't find the DLL.

Comment: The OP is using `CodeCompileUnit` for something he has not explained.  I believe that's why this question is so confusing.